# Database Designer/Editor for Browser

Tags: asp.net, database

Someone at my office asked me to build a browser tool to let them specify a database table's columns and then let them edit the rows.  I would be happy to do that, but it seems like this must have been written before or is part of some CMS tool out there.  **Is there a tool/service/website that lets user create simple database schemas that can then be editted?**  I am looking for a very simple tool.  That really amounts to a simple table editor.  It doesn't need to know about foreign keys or indexes.  Something like multiple people editing a spreadsheet on Google docs but only let users edit one row at a time.

Extra points for an ASP.NET/MVC tool.

Comment: I don't allow users to change db schemas personally. This is virtually always a bad idea. Especially "power users"; they can cause horrible damage to a database's integrity

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is what you looking for but have a look at phpMyAdmin.
It is a tool for mySql to manage databases, table, user, and data of a mySql installation.
It is a php written webfrontend.

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I think this is fancier than I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for your needs, but we use [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) to manipulate our databases.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a tutorial that shows you how to install phpMyAdmin on your server. The designer mode makes it simple to manage your database and it runs in your browser. This tutorial shows you how http://havenofcode.com/tutorial.php?tut=9.